# "You've said so time and again"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I have come accross an unusual to me form of sentence from "The curious Savage": "You’ve got me in such a state, I can’t think. I haven’t a brain in my head, anyhow—you’ve said so time and again.". What dows "you've said so time and again" mean? Does it mean "You've said it once and now you are saying it again"?

Comment: It means "You have said it many times" - a slight contraction of _time and time again_.

Comment: It's in the dictionary.

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("no research"). Hi Timur, our [Help Centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says "questions about the following topics ... are out of scope for this site. # *The meaning of words, or synonyms for words, unless you have first looked them up in a dictionary or thesaurus*." If that doesn't help, [edit] your question to tell us what you found and where the confusion remains. For further guidance, see [ask] and take the EL&U**[Tour]**. :-)

Comment: Timur, you may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find trivial. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Answer (score 1):

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:

***time and again***

: FREQUENTLY, 
REPEATEDLY

(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/time%20and%20again)

See an example from Reverso.context.net:

The Agreement, with both military and civilian components, ***time and again*** proved to be without an alternative.